# Response body using Http DELETE using OkHttp or RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, okhttp

I am unable to read response body after making a DELETE request. I have tried both okhttp and RestTemplate. I do get the response if I use Postman for the same DELETE request.

Here is my code using okhttp. I do see the response code as 202, but response body is null. Am I missing something here?

```
private String httpDelete(HttpHeaders httpHeaders, String url) throws IOException {
    Request.Builder builder = new Request.Builder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : httpHeaders.entrySet()) {
        for (String value : entry.getValue()) {
            builder.addHeader(entry.getKey(), value);
        }
    }
    Request request = builder
            .url(url)
            .delete(null)
            .build();

    okhttp3.Response response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
}
```

Tried RestTemplate as well, body is always null, but response code is 202.

```
ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, serviceRequestHttpEntity, String.class);
        body = exchange.getBody();
        if (body != null) {
            Response response = objectMapper.readValue(body, Response.class);
            return String.valueOf(response.getTaskResponse().getTaskId());
        }
```

Edit: Here are the response headers

```
 Server - nginx
 Date - Fri, 08 Nov 2019 13
 Content-Type - application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Transfer-Encoding - chunked
 Connection - keep-alive
 Accept-Encoding - gzip, deflate
 Accept - application/json
 usercontext - eyJ1c2VyTmFtZSI6InNuYXBhcGl1c2VyMDEiLCJ1c2VyUm9sZXMiOlsiUHJvdmlkZXJEYXRhQ2VudGVyQWRtaW4iXSwidGVuYW50TmFtZSI6IiJ9
 Set-Cookie - JSESSIONID=F6C091C167F9751554B74A7B4A7CDB4F; Path=/; HttpOnly
 Response-Time - Fri, 08 Nov 2019 13
 X-Forwarded-For - 10.26.34.40
 X-Content-Type-Options - nosniff
 X-Frame-Options - DENY
 X-Real-IP - <hidden>
 User-Agent - okhttp/4.2.2
 Expires - 0
 X-XSS-Protection - 1; mode=block
 Cookie - JSESSIONID=39168C2CDF74AE7A69B1C8A38E5DCBF4
 override - override-with-referred-template
 X-Forwarded-Proto - https
```

Comment: can you provide the response headers?

Comment: what response code do you get in postman ?

Comment: @MaxPeng Added headers in the question

Comment: @Deadpool Response code is 202

Comment: a 202 with a response body seems like a weird "not supposed to happen" situation. If you have a response body to give, then return a status code 200. OkHttp likely is designed to take a 202 as it should be taken.

Comment: @Gimby Postman is able to show the response